Angular Echarts not rendering in mat-side-nav
I have an application that retrieves data from a backend process and then creates several echart graphs dynamically on the front end. I never know how many charts will be created, so I can't set static elements for the charts. If I create a div and use *ngFor for the charts in the main page, the charts render just fine. However, I would like to open a side nav and have the charts render there. In the side nav, I get the frames for the charts and the titles, etc, but there is no graph rendering in the side nav. I have tried passing the data to the side nav via a service and creating the options and charts in afterViewInit and also building the charts in the main program and passing all the chart data in via a service. I get the same results either way. The template for the charts is:
    <div  style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 60px; overflow-y: auto; z-index: 995;max-height:90%; min-height:23vh; width: 98%;">
    
    <div class="graphwindow" >
        <div *ngFor="let p of qualprofs" style="border:solid 1px; " >
            
            <p class="graph-heading"  style="padding-left:5px;"> 
            <span  style="font-size: 9px;">
                {{p.shortTitle}} 
            </span>
            <span  style="float:right;z-index:999;">
                
                <nb-icon icon="arrow-ios-downward-outline" ></nb-icon>
            </span>
            <span  style="float: right;z-index:999;" >
                <nb-icon icon="expand-outline" ></nb-icon>     
                <nb-icon icon="arrow-ios-upward-outline" ></nb-icon>
            </span> 

            </p>
            <div style="height:100%;border: solid 1px; width: 100%; font-size:9px;" >
                <div echarts [options]="p.echtdata"  (chartMouseMove)="profileMousemove($event,p)"  class="demo-chart" style="height:250px;">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

And the corresponding TS file is:
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ GlobalVars } from '../../common/globals';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';
import { Map,LatLng,icon,LayerGroup, marker } from 'leaflet';
import { MapService } from 'src/app/map.service';
import { ProfileService } from 'src/app/profile.service';
import type { EChartsOption } from 'echarts';
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profiles',
  templateUrl: './profiles.component.html',
  styleUrl: './profiles.component.scss'
})
export class ProfilesComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  map: Map;

  qualprofs: any;
  profMouseObj:any;


  constructor(
    
    public apiService: ApiService,
    private router: Router,
    public profileService: ProfileService) { 
      
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(){

     this.profileService.data$.subscribe(data => {
      this.qualprofs = data;
    })

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.qualprofs = [];
  }

} 

I'm sharing the data through a simple service called ProfileService:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfileService {
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();

  setData(data: any) {
    this.dataSubject.next(data);
  }
}

If I add the html code from the template in the main viewing area (not in the side-nav) Everything displays fine. I'm simply trying to pass the chart data array to the side-nav and then draw the charts there instead, but I can't figure out why the graphs won't render. Attached is a pic of the side-nav after the data is returned followed by just throwing the div on the main application.
side-nav-render
This is in the main app:
main app render
